# Skewness in residuals

Tags: regression, residuals, robust, skewness

I have skewness of -0.5 in the residuals which does not seem to be improve much after using logs/root.
Is this a major concern?  Tests relating to homoskedasticity, multicollinearity, outliers all seem fine. Perhaps interpreting the regression using robust standard errors would help..

Comment: why don't ypu post your data and your results. Perhaps then someome might be able to help.

Comment: -0.5 is not much skewness; I don't think this should be a concern unless there are other problems (e.g outliers).

Comment: Peter,  or changes in the error variance or changes in the parameters

Comment: Glen - I have 0 values in the data, what other transformations do you suggest which would you suggest trying? (mboxcox proved to be not very useful).  The dependent variable is investment in dollars. Explanatory variables include age; and a number of binary indicators.

Comment: There's not really enough information to make any reasonable suggestion

Answer (score 2):

> I have skewness of -0.5 in the residuals which does not seem to be improve much after using logs/root.

*Of course* it's not going to improve. If your skewness is negative, why are you taking transformations that would *tend to make it smaller*? What is your basis for choosing those transformations?

> Is this a major concern?

If you mean 'should I worry about mild negative skewness in residuals', then that depends on what you're doing the regression for. If you need accurate *prediction* intervals, then it may be a bigger problem than if you need CIs... but without a better picture of what's going on, it's difficult to say much of anything sensible.

Why are you doing the regression? What is the response (IV) and how is it measured? What are the variables? What questions are you trying to answer? What do the residuals *look* like? Are they random against the predictor(s)? Are there influential points?